# Retrofit2 + RxJava2 + RxAndroid error

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

I am getting error message as below when try to crate `Subscriber` and subscribe.

```
can not resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous rx.Subscriber<GooglePlacesResponse>)'
```

**build.gradle**

```
// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1
```

**GooglePlaceService.java**

```
public interface GooglePlaceService {

    public static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "google_api_key";

    @GET("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=2000&key="+GOOGLE_API_KEY)
    Observable<GooglePlacesResponse> getNearbyPlaces(@Query("location") String location);
}
```

**ApiUtils.java**

```
public class ApiUtils {    

    public static final String GOOGLE_PLACE_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/";

    public static GooglePlaceService getGooglePlaceService() {
        return getClient(GOOGLE_PLACE_BASE_URL).create(GooglePlaceService.class);
    }

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Observable `Observable<GooglePlacesResponse>` is as below.

```
Observable<GooglePlacesResponse> mGooglePlacesResponseObervable = ApiUtils.getGooglePlaceService().getNearbyPlaces(latitude + "," + longitude);

mGooglePlacesResponseObervable
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(new Subscriber<GooglePlacesResponse>() { <-- Error here : can not resolve method `subscribe(anonymous rx.Subscriber<GooglePlacesResponse>)`

            @Override
            public void onNext(GooglePlacesResponse googlePlacesResponse) {

                }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
     });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RxJavaCallAdapter` returns a RxJava 1 `Observable`.  You should use [`RxJava2CallAdapter`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2) for RxJava2.  Looks like that is not in an official retrofit release yet, but is in the 2.1.1 snapshot.  You can either compile the adapter yourself, or pull the dependencies off the sonatype snapshot repo.

Add the following to your `repositories` section in your `build.gradle` --

```
repositories {
    // Other repos...
    maven {
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}
```

Update your retrofit dependencies to the `2.1.1-SNAPSHOT` version.  Note that we also change `adapter-rxjava` to `adapter-rxjava2` --

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

and update your retrofit builder to use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();
```

When 2.1.1 is released, you can go back to the regular dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

The fact that adapter has version `2.*.*` does not mean that it is intended for use with RxJava 2

You should use the official adapter for the *second* version of RxJava:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0' // works with RxJava 2
```

Then you can add factory:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Here is the [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140375/3675659).

Comment: this really saved me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my build.gradle setting, perhaps this would help others

```
depencies{
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to update the retrofit version. [Here](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop) is one very good library to convert to and from `RxJava1.x` to `RxJava2.x` objects. 
First, add this
`compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-interop:0.10.2"`
to `build.gradle` and Use method
 `RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(observableRx1)`
to convert to Rx2 Observables.